# docker compose that schedule crontab like ansible dry-run from an external docker image

Tags: docker-compose

I have a docker compose stack that has these 3 services

- *task_scheduler*: a simple scheduler, as crond (I used yacron, simple)
- a fake service *installsoft* that embed the ansible code that configure remote servers
- *httpd* a simple python http server to see output files of the *installsoft* service

This *installsoft* service is an external docker image that is offered by another service.

In a compose file, I don't know how to identify a service that acts as a lambda, rather than a running service ... Did I not RTFM enough ?
When I do a docker compose up, it tries to start all "services", but on is just a task.

I would like to have this *installsoft* being in the same network as the stack so that it can share network, volumes ...

How do you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

After internal discussions, I extracted the scheduler out of the compose in a single Dockerfile.
This dockerfile stores a `services/compose.yaml` where services can be started, the http and the one shot *installsoft*.

The entry point start the service http using the compose

```
services:
  task_scheduler:
    command:
      - |
        cd /yacron/services/
        docker compose up http ssh_tunnel -d
        cd /yacron
        yacron --log-level INFO --config /yacron/conf/top.yml
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

and yacron/services/compose.yaml

```
services:
  http:
    image: 'python:3'
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:${HTTP_PORT}:80
    volumes:
      - data:/data/
  installsoft:
    command: ansible-playbook ...
    volumes:
      - data:/data/
```

And the `installsoft` service can be run with this yacron job

```
jobs:
  - name: do_installsoft
    command: docker compose run --build installsoft > /data/installsoft.log
    shell: /bin/bash
    schedule: "45 6 * * 0-5"
    timezone: "Europe/Paris"
```